# Add link to my module output

Tags: 7

I have many field for my custom module.

And output:

```
    if($slides->rowCount() > 0 ){
        $output .= '<ul id="head_slider" class="clearfix">';
        foreach($slides as $sld):
            $nd = node_load($sld->nid);
            if(count($nd->field_simage) >  0){
                $img_url = image_style_url('img_960x378',$nd->field_simage['und'][0]['uri']);
            }
            $output .= '<li><img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$sld->title.'" /></li>';
        endforeach;
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }


    return $output;
}
```

Content type has url field. It's name `field_surl` When users insert a link to this field, must wrap this link to my output.

I tried this but not working:

```
$output .= '<li><a href="'.$field_surl.'"><img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$sld->title.'" /></a></li>';
```

Result of this output:

```
<a href='field_surl'>...</a>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the result of your actual code? And where do you get the $field_surl variable?

Comment: Please, clarify if $field_surl variable is used for internal or external links (or both).

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: try using https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the few things I know about your field field_surl and about the way you tried to solve it, I might purpose this simple answer, sorry if it sounds obvious :

You wrote :

```
$output .= '<li><a href="'.$field_surl.'"><img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$sld->title.'" /></a></li>';
```

Where did you initialize your $field_surl variable ? At least, assuming $field_surl is loaded within the same node, try :

```
$output .= '<li><a href="'.$nd->field_surl.'"><img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$sld->title.'" /></a></li>';
```

Or even better, as suggested in @Brandon comment, use url() function :

```
$options = array('absolute'=>TRUE); //i.e, or set whatever options you need for your url
$my_url = url($nd->field_surl, $options);
$output .= '<li><a href="'.$my_url.'"><img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$sld->title.'" /></a></li>';
```